# Battery indicator doesn't change its status (but after reboot)

Tags: 12.04, indicator, battery

The problem is the same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185137/battery-status-in-panel-does-not-change-or-give-low-battery-warning-ubuntu-12-0):

> 1. The icon does not change when the power cord is plugged in or
>      unplugged (the icon remains a battery if that was the power source on
>      boot but won't change if I plug in the power adaptor and visa-verse).
> 2. The battery indicator does not give me a low battery warning or alert
>      (ubuntu just shuts down with no onscreen warnings).

Info:

- I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 Bit
- Reinstalling `gnome-power-manager` didn't work
- `acpi -b` returns "Battery 0: Unknown, 95%"

Comment: And did the answer given [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185137/battery-status-in-panel-does-not-change-or-give-low-battery-warning-ubuntu-12-0) help?

Comment: It didn't. I don't have `aptitude` so I used `apt-get` to remove and reinstall it.

Comment: Exactly same issue here.

Comment: I think then that you may need to break this down. gnome-power-manager uses  the package UPower.  So you will probably have this installed. When you run `upower --monitor-detail` and disconnect/reconnect from an outlet do you see detail lines from that? (I tried and I do)

Comment: Have you done "update-icon-caches"

Comment: So, acpi -b shows the correct value?

Comment: @Benjamin - how old or how new is your notebook ?! In case the accumulator has a chip-error you are obliged to a new accumulator by warranty. Simply check out and send the accumulator to the manufacturer of your notebook. What brand is your notebook ?!

Comment: I had the same error with my previous install of Linux Mint. On my fresh install it's not a problem any more.

Comment: Try:

    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-power-manager && sudo apt-get install gnome-power-manager
Purging the config files may help.  Also make sure there are no related config files in ~/.config

Comment: @Benjamin + pull out the accumulator and setting it in again, could help too.

Comment: Another thing to try is shutting the computer down, pulling the battery out, unplugging the computer,  hitting the power button a few times, plugging everything back in, and turning the computer on again.  Also, does the LiveCD have the same problem?

Comment: You could also try using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` on the off chance it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little weird better answer if your problem is still not solved. I wrote a small python script to show the battery status and its percentage.
But the only problem is that you need to run the script every time you need to see the status.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
process=Popen(['upower','-i','/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0'],stdout=PIPE)
process1=Popen(['grep','-E','state|to\ full|percentage'],stdin=process.stdout,stdout=PIPE)

answer=process1.stdout.read().split('\n')
answer.pop()
final=[]
for i in range(len(answer)):
    temp=answer[i].split(':')
    final.append(temp[0].strip(' ')+' : '+temp[1].strip(' '))

string=''
for i in final:
    string+=i+'\n
string=string.strip('\n')

Popen(['notify-send',string])
```